# how to get next item in a column for Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a button that when you click on it grabs the value of the next value in that column. So far, haven't been able to make it work.

```
$('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        idx = $(e.target).closest("tr").index() + 3, // this starts at row 1
        dataItem = grid.dataItem("tr:eq(" + idx + ")"), // this grabs the data items
        dataItemTotal = dataItem.evalCriteria; // this grabs the value of the selected column and row.
        var test = $(dataItemTotal).next(dataItem); // im trying to get the next ( evalCriteria ) in the next row.
        console.log(test);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just increment idx by 1 to get the next row, use the row to get the dataItem? i.e.(from my linked demo):

```
var selected = grid.select();
if (selected.length > 0) {
   var currentItem = grid.dataItem(selected);
   var selectedIdx = $(selected).closest("tr").index();
   var nextIdx = selectedIdx + 1;
   var nextRow = grid.tbody.find("tr:eq(" + nextIdx + ")")
   var nextItem = grid.dataItem(nextRow);

   console.log(currentItem.ProductName, nextItem.ProductName);
}
```

Here's a demo that I think does what you want: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/ODURUb
But it uses a button outside the grid and acts on the currently selected row, so determining the current row is slightly different than your code where the button looks like it is in the row...shouldn't matter, the technique should be the same after you get the current dataItem.